# Convert Sql query (Many to Many) to Django ORM query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Please let me know, Is it possible to convert the following query to Django query (Without using raw).

**NOTE:** updated the raw query

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
               "auth_user"."password",
               "auth_user"."last_login",
               "auth_user"."is_superuser",
               "auth_user"."username",
               "auth_user"."first_name",
               "auth_user"."last_name",
               "auth_user"."email",
               "auth_user"."is_staff",
               "auth_user"."is_active",
               "auth_user"."date_joined",
               "chat_roomdetails"."room",
               "chat_roomdetails"."room_name",
               "chat_roomdetails"."room_type",
               "chat_roomdetails"."is_active"

        FROM   "auth_user"
        LEFT JOIN ("chat_roomdetails_participants"
            INNER JOIN ("chat_roomdetails"
                INNER JOIN "chat_roomdetails_participants" AS ROOM ON
                    (ROOM."roomdetails_id" = "chat_roomdetails"."id" AND ROOM."user_id" = {LOGIN_USER_ID})
                )  ON ("chat_roomdetails"."id" = "chat_roomdetails_participants"."roomdetails_id")
            )
            ON ("chat_roomdetails_participants"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
        WHERE  "auth_user"."is_superuser" = false
        GROUP BY ("auth_user"."id");
```

Here is my RoomDetails model:

```
class RoomDetails(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=8,
                            unique=True,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            verbose_name="Room unique name (Randomly generate)")
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                 blank=False,
                                 null=False)
    room_type = models.IntegerField(choices=RoomType, default=RoomType[0][0])
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                                    verbose_name="Is room Active")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Requirement: After login, the User can see all the user(Except superuser) with roomdetails (Contain only logged In User's belonging roomdertails, Not all roomdertails). 
The relation between RoomDetails and User has many-to-many.

Comment: Is it pssible to specify *what* you aim to do? Not that much *how* you want to do this?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , I feel this can be done by using the Django ORM Query, instead of a raw query. I tried many things but did not get the solution. hopping any pro-Django devloper guild me to resolve this thing.

Comment: of course it can. But often things are easier when you explain *what* you aim to retrieve, not *how* (with what query). This is the famous XY-problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I already mentioned the requirement:
"Requirement: After login, the User can see all the user(Except superuser) with roomdetails (Contain only logged In User's belonging roomdertails, Not all roomdertails). The relation between RoomDetails and User has many-to-many"